# Alternative uses of the keyword "anyObject", or an efficient way of correcting overlapping images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, overlap

I have seen the keyword anyObject used in the following way many times now:

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
```

Imagine this scenario. I have determined an X and Y pixel that I want to place a UIImageView object. Before placing it, I want to check that there are no other images at this Pixel location to prevent an overlap. My images are snapping to a grid, so I know the exact pixel location this way.

I am trying to determine the syntax to move anyObject from that determined pixel location, to a new location I have already determined. Thanks for any considerations into this topic.

Comment: `anyObject` is not a keyword, just a message like any other. And you speak about determined location, you mean programmatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AnyObject is simply a way to index into an NSArray.  The question you're asking is slightly more complicated, as it involves querying a window for a list of children, then requesting of EACH (not any) the coordinates to prevent collision.

I recommend some light reading at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html

Specifically pay attention to subviews, frames and bounds.   Good luck!!

Comment: Thanks for that. The obvious explanation has always been to poll all objects on the screen. I'm looking at 100 objects on the screen, and I'm already completing 100 or so checks to get to this point. I might just try this route and see how it performs.